# Google Static Map API - image map with 25+ points

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, google-maps-static-api

I am trying to create map of the track with 30 or so points with Google Static Map API. The problem is that it supports only origin-23waypoints-end even with premium key. So the idea I got is to split the route into two and then merge those two images. The problem is that since the parts of the track will have different points it means that the map canvas won't be same which renders the merge (almost?) impossible.

Anybody would have any idea how to solve this issue? I am helpless.

Thank you very much for any ideas. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no good way to do this, to best of my knowledge.

When solving the problem, we just went with multiple maps in the end. Everything is solvable yet this was not worth investing the time.

It's technically not an answer but an information for anybody attempting this. If you would be able to solve this, please post your solution here and I will mark it.